# How can I sort a UITableView using CoreData information

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

Right now I use this func to fetch my `UITableView` and it works fine, but I want to sort it by `"dataUltimei"` which is a date (ex: 07.08.2017). I don't know why but it doesn't sort the table. This is my code:

```
func fetch() {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dataUltimei", ascending: true)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Contact")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        contacts = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using fetchResultViewController?

Comment: Yes, I'm using fetchResultViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing the date **as a string**, you will not be able to get Core Data to sort it **as a date**. Core Data doesn't know that your string is a date, so it sorts it using string rules instead of numeric date comparisons, which is what you're seeing.

If you need to sort by date, **you need to have a date**. Save the date in Core Data as a date field and sort on that value. Then use a `DateFormatter` to convert the date to a string for your UI.

Sorting would probably work if you formatted the date string as year-month-day, something like `2017-08-22`. But comparing strings like this will be much much slower than comparing dates. It might give the right sorting result but only with much worse performance.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that my func sorts the tabel but not in the way I want. "dataUltimei" represents the date as a string (June,12,2017) and it sorts it alphabetically. Now I'm trying to convert my date type (June,12,2017) into something like this (06.12.2017) and maybe it will work

Comment: I would suggest storing a date as a Date, and not a string.  When you need to display it use a `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: Or rather its native Swift counterpart, `DateFormatter`.